# Decode Base64VecU8 to Vec<u8> and merge with another Vec<u8>

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

I'm attempting to merge a JSON string as `Vec<u8>` with the result of decoding a `Base64VecU8` value:

```rust
pub fn decode_and_merge(&mut self, args: Base64VecU8) {
    // This unwraps correctly
    let args_des: Vec<u8> = serde_json::to_string(&args).unwrap().into_bytes();
    // This also returns a Vec<u8>
    let args_des = args.0;

    // But when trying to extend, append or merge:

    let init_fn_args = [
        Into::<Vec<u8>>::into(args_des)[..],
        serde_json::json!({ "market_creator_account_id": env::signer_account_id() })
            .to_string()
            .into_bytes()[..],
    ];

    let promise = Promise::new("cc".to_string())
        .create_account()
        .deploy_contract(MARKET_CODE.to_vec())
        .transfer(env::attached_deposit())
        .function_call(
            "new".to_string(),
            init_fn_args, // FAILS with expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found array `[[u8]; 2]`
            0,
            GAS_FOR_CREATE_MARKET,
        );

    // Also tried with

    let init_fn_args = args_des.extend(
        serde_json::json!({ "market_creator_account_id": env::signer_account_id() })
            .to_string()
            .into_bytes(),
    );

    let promise = Promise::new("cc".to_string())
        .create_account()
        .deploy_contract(MARKET_CODE.to_vec())
        .transfer(env::attached_deposit())
        .function_call(
            "new".to_string(),
            init_fn_args, // FAILS with expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found `()`
            0,
            GAS_FOR_CREATE_MARKET,
        );
}
```

The most confusing part is `expected struct 'std::vec::Vec', found '()'`. I still don't understand why it results in `()` instead of the `Vec`

The full compiler errors for the first attempt:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/contract.rs:69:47
   |
69 |             .function_call("new".to_string(), init_fn_args, 0, GAS_FOR_CREATE_MARKET);
   |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Vec`, found array `[[u8]; 2]`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Vec<u8>`
               found array `[[u8]; 2]`
```

The full compiler errors for the second attempt:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/contract.rs:69:47
   |
69 |             .function_call("new".to_string(), init_fn_args, 0, GAS_FOR_CREATE_MARKET);
   |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Vec`, found `()`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Vec<u8>`
           found unit type `()`
```

Comment: can you provide a full copy of the compiler errors?

Answer (score 2):

The first version didn't work because `[...]` creates an array, not a `Vec`. To fix it, you should use `vec![...]` instead.

The second version didn't work because `Vec::extend()` works by side effect and therefore doesn't return a value. (This is very much like Python where `list.append` or `list.sort` return `None`.) To fix it, you should call `args_des.extend(...whatever...)` and then use `args_des` instead of `init_fn_args` (or declare a `let init_fn_args = args_des;` after the call to `extend()`).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers, what finally worked is this:

```rust
pub fn merge(&mut self, args: Base64VecU8) -> Promise {
        let mut init_args: Value = serde_json::from_slice(&args.0.as_slice()).unwrap();

        init_args.as_object_mut().unwrap().insert(
            "another_arg".to_string(),
            Value::String(env::signer_account_id().to_string()),
        );

// ...
```